# How can I share my Macbook's Network to iPhone, surpassing the 802.1X protection?

Tags: iphone, mac, network, ethernet, 802.1x

My school provides ethernet, which my Macbook can easily connect to. I want to share it with my iPhone, but it indicates that 802.1X protection has forbidden me to do so. Is there a way to surpass the protection?

Operating system: OS X 10.10 with iOS 8.4

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Usually on school campus you'll have wifi too, and also 802.1X protection is there for a reason.

The only way to share internet from a 802.1X protected network , I think, is by creating a VPN connection on the mac (this will only work if your school's network allows it which i doubt).

To do this go to your nettwork settings, unlock it (padlock) and click the plus sign to add a VPN connection.

Next you choose VPN connection, in this example i'll be using vpnbook.com/freevpn since it provides a free reliable service. So change the type to PPTP.

Now the interface is created and you need to put the credentials provided in the free PPTP section of vpnbook.com/freevpn (vpn server / login / password)

hit connect and it should work

[image]

The last thing now is to share this VPN connection, you need to go back to share settings and choose the interface you just created

[image]
I can't post more than two links(images) since this is a new profile, if you need more help comment.

Comment: It would be helpful if the images were in English. What does PPTP stand for anyway?